# Convert byte-stream to character-stream in Java

Tags: java, arrays, encoding, stream, character

Is there a class where one can create it by specifying the encoding, feed byte streams into it and get character streams from it? The main point is I want to conserve memory by not having *both* entire byte-stream data and entire character-stream data in the memory at the same time.

Something like:

```
Something s = new Something("utf-8");
s.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // it converts the bytes directly to characters internally, so we don't store both
// ... several more s.write() calls
s.close(); // or not needed

String text = s.getString();
// or
char[] text = s.getCharArray();
```

What is that `Something`?

Comment: You want to start with a huge byte[] buffer and end with a huge String text without needing memory for both? If so, forget it, this can't work. Something starting with byte[] and returning a CharSequence (accessing the buffer) would be possible, but is it worth it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably mock it up using `CharsetDecoder`.  Something along the lines of

```
    CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName(encoding).newDecoder();
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.allocate(100);
    decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer1), cb, false);
    decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer2), cb, false);
    ...
    decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bufferN), cb, true);
    cb.position(0);
    return cb.toString();
```

(Yes, I know this will overflow your `CharBuffer` -- you may want to copy the contents into a `StringBuilder` as you go.)

Comment: If you actually do have an `InputStream` and not just a series of `byte[]` buffers, then `InputStreamReader` is the right way to go...

Comment: Google returned this answer for another question I had, and I just have to warn that this code does not properly handle utf-8 if 2 or 3 byte character is split up between buffer1 and buffer2. You have to check that the entire buffer is read.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for `ByteArrayInputStream`?  You could then wrap that in a `InputStreamReader` and read characters out of the original byte array.

A `ByteArrayInputStream` lets you "stream" from a byte array. If you wrap that in an `InputStreamReader` you can read characters.  The `InputStreamReader` lets you stipulate the character encoding.

If you want to go *directly* from an input source of bytes, then you can just construct the appropriate sort of `InputStream` class (`FileInputStream` for example) and then wrap that in an `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: Well, that's true, but there will be some time in memory that both byte-array data and character-array data exist at the same time. Is it possible to have that Something converts byte-stream to character-array as the byte-stream is input? (We lose that raw byte-stream data, but we only need that character-array output). I'll clarify that on the question.

Comment: If you open a file as a Stream, and then wrap a Reader around the Stream instance, then the only thing to worry about is incidental buffering. You won't be filling up memory with two versions of the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code didn't seem to indicate that a character stream was needed. If so, `String` can already handle all that you want. Assuming `String s` contains the data,

```
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes("utf-8");
```

The question then reduces to how to get bytes from a byte stream into `String`, for which you can use `ByteArrayOutputStream`, like so:

```
ByteArrayOutputSteam os = new ByteArrayOutputSteam();
os.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // it just stores the bytes, doesn't convert yet.
// several more os.write() calls
s = os.toString("utf-8"); // now it converts the full buffer to a string in the specified encoding.
```

If you truly want something that has a byte input stream and a character output stream, there isn't a built-in one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the title "*Convert byte-stream to character-stream in Java*" contradicts your example using no streams at all but **arrays**. I'm assuming further you want arrays.

You surely can't start with byte[] and end with char[] (or String) without having both somewhere for a while. There are however some possibilities:

- in case you really need a `char[]`: Idea: Write the byte[] into a file and read it using a FileReader into the array. This doesn't really work, since you don't know the proper array length in advance. So generate and write all the characters into a file using DataOutput, read all of them back using DataInput into an array.
- in case you really need a `String`: Create a `char[]` as above and use reflection and `setAccessibe(true)` to invoke the package-private ctor `String(int offset, int count, char value[])`.
- in case a `CharSequence` suffices: Create a class MyCharSequence holding the byte[]. An extremely slow solution would be to implement its method `charAt(index)` by converting a part of the byte[] starting from the beginning until you obtain `index+1` chars. Discard all of them on the fly and keep the last one. Such a stupid method is needed since using `utf8` you don't know how many bytes corresponds with a single char. You could do it once at the beginning and remember for each char the position of its first byte. This is even more stupid, as you'd need much more memory for those positions. Fortunately, a simple space-time tradeoff exists, e.g., remember the position of the first byte for each 16th char.

All my proposals are a bit strange, but I believe, it can't be done much better. It could be a funny homework, I wouldn't go for it.